# Selenium chromedriver threadlocal multiprocessing issue - How to quit/close all Selenium drivers in multiprocessng to manage memory leakage?

Tags: python, selenium, multiprocessing

I'm having difficulty figuring out how to close the browsers/drivers & clear the memory in order to manage a memory leakage of a Selenium-based webscraper.  I have built a web-scraper to scrape a long list of URLs in parallel.  Unfortunately there is a memory leak, and I need to close the browsers and clear the memory periodically in order to manage it.

I've tried using `driver.quit()` and `driver.close()`, however the browsers don't close/quit [i.e., `getattr(threadLocal,'browser', None)` can still find the browser objects].  I've also tried using `driver.get().quit()`, however an error gets raised stating I need to include a 'URL' into the get-statement.

I've built a small test example here, and I would really appreciate any help.  Thanks!

```
selenium_browser_test.py

import multiprocessing as mp
from selenium_browser_quit import SeleniumBrowserQuit


class SeleniumBrowserTest:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def simpleTest(self):
        selenium_browser_quit = SeleniumBrowserQuit()
        results = []
        for i in range(0,10,1):
            results.append(self.worker(i))
        selenium_browser_quit.quitDrivers()
        return

    def multiprocessingTest(self):
        inputs = []
        for i in range(0,10,1):
            inputs.append(i)
        pool = mp.get_context("spawn").Pool(mp.cpu_count())    
        results = pool.map(self.worker, inputs)
        print(results)
        selenium_browser_quit = SeleniumBrowserQuit()
        selenium_browser_quit.quitDrivers()
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        return

    def worker(self,x):
        print(x*x)
        selenium_browser_quit = SeleniumBrowserQuit()
        browser_driver = selenium_browser_quit.create_browser()
        return x*x


if __name__ == '__main__':
    selenium_browser_test = SeleniumBrowserTest()
    selenium_browser_test.simpleTest()
    print('--------------------------')
    selenium_browser_test.multiprocessingTest()
```

---

```
selenium_browser_quit.py

import threading
from selenium import webdriver

threadLocal = threading.local()

class SeleniumBrowserQuit:
    def __init__(self):
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument("--headless")
        options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches',['enable-logging'])
        #
        user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36'
        options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
        options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
        assert options.headless 
        #self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
        pass

    @classmethod
    def create_browser(cls):
        print('Create browser function')
        # Step 1: Testing the state of the browser (if it exists or not)
        browser = getattr(threadLocal,'browser', None)
        print('Browser state:', browser)
        #
        # Step 2: Only starting a new browser if one isn't already running      
        if browser is None:
            browser = cls()
            threadLocal.browser = browser
        #
        # Step 3: Returning the driver
        return browser.driver
    
    def quitDrivers(self):
        browser = getattr(threadLocal,'browser', None)
        print('Broswer: ', browser)
        print('Broswer.driver: ',browser.driver)
        print('Broswer.driver.close(): ')
        self.driver.close()
        del browser
        browser = getattr(threadLocal,'browser', None)
        print('Browser state',browser)
        print('------------')
        print('Browser.driver.quit()')
        self.driver.quit()
        del browser
        browser = getattr(threadLocal,'browser', None)
        print('Browser state',browser)
        return
```

Comment: I don't remember specifically, but I once created a method to kill all "chromedriver.exe" processes running. With Java, I did something like this: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM chromedriver.exe")`. This is the only way know how and worked pretty good. This might not be the exact code, but it is pretty close and should give you an idea how to do it in Python.

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73899334/python-selenium-close-all-instances-of-webdriver#73987157).